# Bash setting array name to variable value

Tags: bash

I am having an issue trying to set and populate an array who's name should be the value of another variable... can anyone help?

```
        mainTID=${pidArray[$pidCounter]}
        tempThreadIDs=`ps -eL | grep ${mainTID} | awk '{ if ( $2 != '$mainTID' ) print $2}'`

        $mainTID=( $tempThreadIDs )
```

mainTID is an integer and I want to call the array whatever that integer is, and then populate it with the list called 'tempThreadIDs'

I thought about using eval, but I really need to keep my overhead down and I couldn't really get it to work correctly... I then attempted to just declare the array first, but I get an error stating that the value (an integer) is 'not a valid identifier'...am I not allowed to call an array a number?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The code seems to be almost completely unrelated to your question.

Comment: What is `ps -eL | grep ${mainTID}` supposed to do?

Comment: You seem to be looking for indirect parameter expansion (consult the man page), but parameter names consisting solely of numerical digits are reserved for the positional parameters.

Comment: @chepner Indirect expansion works the other way. He wants to set into a variable indirectly.

Comment: Variable names (and that includes array names) can't be integers; they must start with a non-numeric character (alpha or underscore).  If you think about it a moment, `$1` already has a meaning in the shell, and so does `${99}` etc.

Comment: @EtanReisner True, although I was addressing the eventual need to access the array named by `mainTID`. (But you can use `declare` to set a parameter indirectly, as well: `foo=bar; declare "$foo=5"; echo "$bar"`.)

Comment: @chepner That usage of declare is indirect variable assignment but not indirect expansion. Indirect expansion is something else and works the other way (though can be used as part of this as well if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

[This section](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#line-205) of the [How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) page of the `BashFAQ` is likely going to be of some use here (though you really should read the whole page).

```
If you need to assign multiline values, keep reading.

A similar trick works for Bash array variables too:

     # Bash/ksh93/mksh/zsh

     typeset readFix=${BASH_VERSION+a}
     aref=realarray
     IFS=' ' read -d '' -r${readFix:-A} "$aref" <<<'words go into array elements'
     echo "${realarray[1]}"   # prints "go"
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Bash does not support multi-dimensional arrays so you could just best store them as strings, but could be parsed easily:

Storing:

```
mainTID=${pidArray[$pidCounter]}
readarray -t VALUES < <(exec ps -eL | awk -v tid="$mainTID" '$1 == tid && $2 != tid { print $2 }')
IFS='|' eval 'STORAGE[$mainTID]="${VALUES[*]}"'
```

Using:

```
mainTID=${pidArray[$pidCounter]}
IFS='|' read -ra VALUES <<< "${STORAGE[$mainTID]}"
for V in "${VALUES[@]}"; do
    # Do something with $V.
done
```

Note: STORAGE is an array variable there. It's quite enough with numbers. However if you're going to use keys besides numbers, just declare it as an associative array parameter before using:

```
declare -A STORAGE
```

Of course you can have your own preferred parameter names and case formats.

And as you may have noticed, I tried to simplify or correct your Awk command. I hope I did it right.

Another note: Using indirect parameter expansion pairing with a prefix+pid named variable is another good idea but would be a bulky pollution to the environment and confusing as you'd have to keep using a reference everytime you'd need to expand a value from the variable.